# Conditions for the validity of the product and quotient rule of differentiation

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$$\frac{d}{dx}(uv)=v\frac{d}{dx}(u)+u\frac{d}{dx}(v)\tag{product rule}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{u}{v})=\frac{v\frac{d}{dx}(u)-u\frac{d}{dx}(v)}{v^2}\tag{quotient rule}$$

The above two rules work when both $u$ & $v$ are differentiable. However, if $v=0$, doesn't the quotient rule fail?

Comment: If $v = 0$ then $u/v$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If $v$ equals zero at $x=p$, then $\displaystyle\frac uv$ is
  undefined there; consequently, the function does not have a derivative there.
- If $v$ is identically zero, then $\displaystyle\frac uv$ is
  undefined; consequently, the function does not have a derivative
  anywhere.

The quotient rule doesn't actually "fail" anywhere; it gives you the derivative of the ratio of two differentiable functions *wherever that derivative exists*.